# Cannot insert data into mysql database using Java (jframe)

Tags: java, mysql, database, jframe, connectivity

I've tried connecting my jframe to mysql database to insert records into the database using jframe but have not been successful yet. I'm having a hard time finding the error(s). The program shows no error while running but does not add values to database. 
Below the database name is `'tanishq'` and `t1`, `t2`, `t3`, `t4` and `t5` are name of the textfields.

Here is my code:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    try {
        Class.forName("java.sql.driver");
        Connection con =
                DriverManager.getConnection
                        (" jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/tanishq" + "user=root& password=...");
        Statement stmt = (Statement) con.createStatement();
        String query = "insert into jewel values
        ('"+t1.getText()+"',
                '"+ t2.getText()+"',
                "+ t3.getText()+",
                "+ t4.getText()+",
                "+ t5.getText()+")";
        System.out.println(query);
        stmt.executeUpdate(query);
        j1.showMessageDialog(null, "RECORD ADDED");
    } catch
            (Exception e) {
        j1.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like it is with the wrong driver used. Try to use 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver' as parameter in your Class.forName method.

Comment: @NarayanaGanesh it now shows an error like " access denied for user  (@)localhost(using password NO) "

Comment: Try to use overloaded version of getConnection method like DriverManager
  .getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/tanishq", "root", "root");

Comment: @NarayanaGanesh ..it worked.
Thank you